# Entity Framework Core database-first selecting specific columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, ef-database-first

```
    public Tbl016 CheckLoginCredentials(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        return
            context.Agents
            .Where(x => x.LoginName == UserName && x.LoginPassword == Password)
            .Select(x => new Tbl016
            {
                LoginName = x.LoginName,
                LoginPassword = x.LoginPassword
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I'm developing an Entity Framework Core API using database-first approach and using a repository design pattern. In the above function I'm trying to retrieve specific columns from the database, but unfortunately, when I run the code, the response body brings data from all the columns in the table.

What I've tried so far is the `.Select new` expression but it is not working.

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you seem to be attempting to use Entity Framework the wrong way. Entity Framework by default updates its context whenever accessing variables from the dbcontext of model from the database if it doesn't already have them, and that's one of its best features. If you only want singular columns from the database you should run your own sql with FromSqlRaw to select your own columns. If you only want to USE or pass back the two variables you are, I recommend making a ViewModel class for those variables and setting them to the dbcontext model data you're pulling from

Comment: @Gen -I'm using reverse engineering EF core because I'm building an API for a software with an existing Database. First of All and unfortunately I don't have a clear picture of EF Core "ViewModel" is it similar to what we do in Xamarin.Forms?. Secondly If I created such a class I might be finding my self in a situation where I need columns other than these two. Shall I create a new "ViewModel" or just one is enough in which I include every single property in the table?

Comment: @Gen Using `Select()` is fine when using Entity Framework. LINQ-to-EF even have support for `Select()` to fetch only the columns needed/requested. There is no need to build your own SQL query with `FromSqlRaw()`.

Comment: it depends on the usage to be honest, if you make a ViewModel that contains those properties you can always add more to it and assign those variables to the class pretty easily. However, if your only point in making a separate class to put the data into is for 'speed' or for 'less SQL' or 'less queries', don't bother. Entity Framework has already updated the context for the item you are accessing, so all of the variables attached to that object are ALREADY updated by the time you're making the viewmodel

Comment: @Progman: sure, depends on his usage, if he uses that object anywhere else with a different property he's getting it updated at that point anyway, so it still depends on the context of the program

Comment: it just depends on whether you need all those objects or not and what your other calls to that table look like, I recommend reading this: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/09/select-specific-columns-entity-framework-query/

Comment: @Gen_@Progman -Correct me if I'm wrong. The VewModel to be created has to have INotifyProperyChanged? or it is just a class that includes properties with set and get

Comment: @mxmissile I'll give it a try

Comment: @mxmissile IntelliSense gave a lot of errors. Probably because I didn't fully understood your point

Comment: @mxmissile Brother you saved my life Thank you. It worked like a charm. my problem is that instead of "dynamic" I used "object". I also changed the type in my abstraction class and boom it Worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return an anonymous object instead:

```
.Select(x => new {
    x.LoginName,
    x.LoginPassword
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

This should only select -> send the 2 columns.

Comment: Yeah.. It worked for me. Of course after I changed the return type of the method. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mxmissile the problem is solved
I changed the return type of the method to dynamic instead of (an Object of the table). then I returned data anonymously in the .Select() method
The full code is:

```
public dynamic CheckLoginCredentials(string UserName, string Password)
{
    return context.Agents
        .Where(x => x.LoginName == UserName && x.LoginPassword == Password)
        .Select(x => new {
            x.LoginName,
            x.LoginPassword
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```